# Removing parent div through .remove();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to remove the parent `div` of a `<button>` tag when pressed. I have this HTML code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(".remove").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parents('.li').remove();
  });
</script>
<div id="1a">
    <input class="versionid" placeholder="Version Number"><button class="add">+</button><button class="remove">X</button><br>
    <br>
    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Changes"></textarea>
</div>
```

The jQuery code should remove the entire `<div id="1a">` block, but nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The selector in `$(this).parents('.li').remove();` refers to the parent you're trying to select. This should read `$(this).parents('#1a').remove();`, notice the change from `'.li'` to `'#1a'`, since the parent div has the id `1a`. Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jLsz6r2/

Alternatively, you could use `$(this).parent().remove()`, which might be easier if you have multiple remove buttons

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a div that's a sibling of .remove, and has a different ID than `#1a` - in case the OP has a different HTML in the present...

Comment: Also `$(this).parent()...` will also be a *fiasco* if it's not the immediate `parent`.

Comment: 1. Don't be salty. 2. currently `#1a` is not a sibling of `.remove`, it's a parent. There should not be multiple elements with the same ID, and if there is then you should rename them, or use a class-- this is not the appropriate solution for that. 3. it's not a _fiasco_ if it's not the immediate parent, you can chain `parent()` until you are selecting the correct element, and 4. If you're using this listener for buttons in different places, you should make sure they behave the exact same. Your comment is simply in retaliation for my perfectly reasonable suggestion on your answer.

Comment: hey I'm not taking anything personally, I like you answer very much, but not as much to give it an upvote. Yes you're right, it's a parent, and NO, `.closest()` should be used instead of `.parent()` IMHO since it's more flexible! Either way, OP should be better using something like a class... But hey we have 2 nice answers (and comments)!! Both should be helpful to OP I hope

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Then you should try to not sounding so sarcastic lol. Maybe you should mention that in your answer, since using `.closest()` when you will always be referencing the parent is definitely not good. There's a reason there are different functions, using them improves clarity and legibility.

Comment: I'm really sorry :( EN is not my primary language. I have mentioned it! Thanks Wade!

Answer (score 1):

Seems a strange parent to remove... since `.parents('.li')` **does not exists**.

```
<div class="YOU DON'T HAVE ANY CLASS" id="1a">
```

Perhaps http://api.jquery.com/closest/:

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

or **rather** assigning a `li` class to your DIV:

```
$(this).closest('.li').remove();
```

like:

```js
$(".remove").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="li" id="1a">
  <input class="versionid" placeholder="Version Number"><button class="add">+</button><button class="remove">X</button><br>
  <br>
  <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Changes"></textarea>
</div>
```

As you can see from the useful comments, make sure to use a more specific selector than `.closest("div")`, perhaps like a class: `.closest(".parent")` or even `.closest(".li")`, but than make sure to use that CLASS `<div class="li" id="1a">`

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a div that's a sibling of `.remove`, in case the OP wants to change their HTML in the future

Comment: **thanks**. On point. @Wade

Comment: just saying. The OP doesn't seem to be too familiar with JS/HTML/CSS, so they might find this useful

Comment: @Wade ofc! thanks again for pointing that out!

Comment: Talk about taking things too personally lol

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the .closest() method: $(this).closest('.li').remove();
It starts with the current element and then climbs up the chain looking for a matching element and stops as soon as it found one.

.parent() only accesses the direct parent of the element, i.e. div.msg-modification which does not match .li. So it never reaches the element you are looking for.

Another solution besides .closest() (which checks the current element and then climbs up the chain) would be using .parents() - however, this would have the caveat that it does not stop as soon as it finds a matching element (and it doesn't check the current element but only parent elements). In your case it doesn't really matter but for what you are trying to do .closest() is the most appropriate method.